# USB Drive Format for Reading/Writing 4GB+ Files on OSX and Windows

Tags: macos, usb, filesystems, usb-flash-drive, file-format

I am trying to settle on a drive file format which is compatible with OSX and Windows for reading/writing 4GB+ files.

Linux support would be a bonus.

- Using FAT is a no go since it does not support 4GB+ files.
- NTFS - appeared good however, OSX cannot write to this format it can only
  read from it.
- OSX Mac file formats - well, that is not going to play
  nice with anything but OSX is it?
- exFAT- I heard it supports 4GB+
  but    there are driver issues I think on OSX?

Anyway, I can't be the first one to look for this, what are other people doing in this regard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X supports exFAT [since 10.6.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT#Adoption). Unless you really need to support older OS X versions you can safely go with exFAT. Linux and FreeBSD might need some fuse-based driver.

Comment: That's good to hear, so OSX and both Windows do not have any issues with exFAT? But Linux still does?

Comment: Depending on the Linux distribution you might already have the right drivers. Other distributions might need some extra work (like [CentOS 6.4](http://yagamy.logdown.com/posts/153972-exfat-on-centos-64))
I had no problems with exFAT on Mountain Lion (10.8) and Mavericks (10.9). I would expect that exFAT works fine with Windows since exFAT is Microsoft's own invention.

Comment: Right I can see that exFat requires a restrictive licence to be implemented which is why I guess most distros' don't come with it by default, at least not kernel level support. However it seems is is quite easy to install on say Ubuntu 13.10+